# Validating the key in the data in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, validation, lumen

I am validating a request that looks like this:

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Foo",     
      "values":{
        "val1":"This",
        "99":"That"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my custom messages:

```
$messages = [
     'data.id'=>'is required',
     'data.name'=>'is required',
     'data.values'=>'must be array',
     'data.values.*'=>'must be numeric'
];
```

My validation rule is this:

```
$this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'data'=>'required|array',
                'data.*.id'=>'required|numeric',
                'data.*.name'=>'required',
                'data.*.values'=>'array',
                'data.*.values.*'=>'numeric'
             ],
            $messages
        );
```

The rule validates the values in the "values" array. I want to validate the key in the "values" array [val1, 99] instead.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking here.  You want to make sure the keys of the `data.*.values` are numeric?

Comment: You probably will need a custom validation.

Comment: Cant you build out the validation based upon the post keys?

Comment: Validated against array_keys()

Comment: @Devon. Yes I wanted to make sure the key are numeric (or test any condition with the keys)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte. That's what my intention is, would you care to show me an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom validation rule for `data.*.values`:

```
'data.*.values' => function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
    //$value contains your array of $key => $value pairs for you to loop through
    if( /* doesn't pass your rules */){
        return $fail('custom validation failed');
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. One more question regarding this function, is it possible to get the value of a variable in the data. EG: if('data.id' == 99){ return $fail('custom validation failed'); }

Comment: @Elymentree if you need values from the main data object, just put the validation on ‘data’ and then loop through it yourself

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!